# can blender auto remove materials and textures if not used over time

Tags: texturing, materials

is it possible for blender to remove files/textures/materials if they havent been used for awhile?

i ask as i got back to looking at models i worked on in blender, but i discovered that one file in particular which was saved, and exported seems to be completely gone, there is a version which has none of the progress done to it but im almost sure i had the file saved as both a .blend and exported as an obj.

i do have the model in another blend file, along with several other models all originally with materials/textures yet even that file seems to have lost them, the names still exist but the colors are gone.

i would check to see if perhaps my files got messed up but as i dont move anything around in the files i use for blender and havent changed anything that could do that i doubt that is the issue. its not a big deal to reassign materials to some things (such as the swords of which i mentioned before, but many of the items are imports from other programs, and have been edited in some way or other (and were textured fine at the time either by default or by me) and those items are far harder to re texture/material as im not particularly skilled with blender even though ive had it for a few years now.

Comment: Did you select ~ File > External Data > Automatically pack into .blend file

Comment: possibly, i likely forgot that part knowing myself.
its odd though as most of the things in the main file are imported from other 3d programs i use and they kept the textures and stuff for a long time and every time i would go back to it everything would be as it should be, then for some reason yesterday i got back on blender after a break and most everything is missing the proper textures.

a couple other things is that on my swords which were missing textures, the materials were made from working addons mainly, so they really shouldnt have been missing.

Comment: Maybe you had it selected long ago, then used a newer version of Blender that didn't have it checked.  I wish it were checked by default.

Comment: perhaps but as far as i recall it was already updated to the version (what it i have now) when i started so shouldnt be an update that did it, but it is possible